# Android google places nearby search

Tags: android, api

I am using Google Places API for searching nearby places. I enabled Google Places API and I need to search for Taj Hotels nearby my current location, So I wrote code like this but I am getting some other names.. Can anyone please help me to do it.

```
btnFind.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String type = "Taj Hotel";

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                    sb.append("location="+mLatitude+","+mLongitude);
                    sb.append("&radius=5000");
                    sb.append("&types="+type);
                    sb.append("&sensor=true");
                    sb.append("&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX e");
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this command it will show nearby places in ascending order

```
    String url= "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+latitude+","+longitude+"&rankby=distance&name="+constraint+"&key="+API_KEY;
```

Refer here for more:-http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-google-places-api/